# Display data if usertype is admin otherwise display error message

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have a list of users in my mysql database. One of the columns is "type". I am trying to display certain data if type is equal to admin. If type is equal to anything else, it should just echo an error message.

Unfortunately, I have tried multiple methods but it just does not seem to be working out for me. Can anyone help me get this to work properly?

This is what I have, but obviously I am doing something wrong....

```
<?php 
$usertype = $_SESSION['type'];
if ($usertype == "admin" ){


?>
admin stuff only goes here
<? 
}
else
  {
  echo "not priveleged usertype";
  }
?>
```

EDIT: 
The following code works when displaying via username, however, I need content displayed by usertype, not the username.

```
<?php 


    if($_SESSION['user']['username'] == "oneoftheadminusernames" ) 
    { 




?>
```

Comment: How do you populate $_SESSION['type'] ?

Comment: what value do you see in $_SESSION['type'] ...?

Comment: By the way.. I think that should be "privileged"

Comment: What is it currently displaying?

Comment: @It'sYourFault It currently is displaying the else function (not priveleged usertype). Please see my edit above, as I can display content per the username logged in, but not the user type.

Comment: try **var_dump($_SESSION);** ; did it show any element by the name **type** ?

Comment: @It'sYourFault It is only displaying user, id, username, & email. First/Last/Type is not showing up. edit: oh shoot i think I know where I went wrong. I have to run now but I may have messed up my mysql insert when registering users. I'll update this again when I return and see if that fixed the issue.

Comment: That lets you know that the type wasn't saved in the session object. Retrace your step back.

Comment: @It'sYourFault Thanks for your help. Ends up being I forgot to retrieve first, last, & type from the database on login. Oops!

Comment: Glad you got it fixed. Do mark the closest answer to the question as correct, in order to help you and others too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each page has to start with

```
<?php 
      @session_start();
?>
```

otherwise, php does not "see" the sessions contents. So that's probably it.
The @ prevents the php error: A session has already been started... by the way.

Now, **every** page that uses the session must have this directive at the top.
At least, in a quick example, that reproduces your error perfectly.

Comment: Don't use **@session_start();** use **if (!isset($_SESSION)){session_start();}**

Comment: Even tidier. Thanks for that mate! Problem being, I've had sessions dissapear into thin air with that construction once their written to by a function.

Comment: Well, that depends on the main problem; so, far, all I see is that it's not working; we need to know what it's currently displaying.

Comment: If the code does not contain the session_start() directive, its safe to say that the comparison looks like: **if (null == "admin")**

Comment: Nope, it should throw an exception, I believe.

Comment: A bit off-topic perhaps, but using a session for this job is quite unsafe by the way. You'd be better off using a public static or something.

Comment: :) Well, I had to find it out for myself, so I see this as extended service to the community. Paying it forward, so to speak.

Comment: Lol....the nature of the OP's question should normally let you know if there are prepared for more advanced stuff; and I don't think he's ready for that yet :)

Comment: I agree, also, I don't believe my answer actually helped him so I'll upvote yours ;)

Comment: True that... but its almost Christmas anyway. Glad you two worked it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are saving each logged in users `type` field in `$_SESSION['type']` variable than the code you are writing is correct. Or if you are storing `type` in another variable than you that variable to check.

Answer (score 0):

i have an idea like add a field  EnableFlag in the table. if enablee flag is set to 1 consider it as a admin else as a User;

Comment: What does that change to the current code? The problem is that the sessions comes up empty, not that the if statement is bogus ;)

Comment: may be like use different table for admin and different table for user.